# How get second port from Heroku for websocket

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku, websocket, socket.io

I'm using Heroku to deploy my nodejs game.
Everything works fine but the websockets on my game won't work when I deploy it to Heroku. 
Heroku gives me 1 available port (in the var port).

Is there a way to get a second port where my socket can listen to?
If I try to set the socket to the same port as the app.listen, it tells me the port is already in use.

```
 var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
 app.listen(port);


 socket = io.listen(8000);
```

Comment: You can have your Socket listen on top of your app: `var server = app.listen(port); socket = io.listen(server);`

Comment: when I do, I also get the following error:
"listen EADDRINUSE"